# Select specific dates from a data frame in python using MODIS data in NETCDF4

Tags: python, date, datetime, netcdf4

I am not well-versed in python, and I'm sure there is a simple solution to this (although, I have looked). I got this code from an lpdaac tutorial.

My input is a NETCDF4 file downloaded from MODIS satellite. Printing the metadata of the file returns the variables

```
file_in = Dataset(file_list[0], 'r', format = 'NETCDF4')
#print metadata
list(file_in.variables)

Out[19]: ['crs', 'time', 'lat', 'lon', '_1_km_16_days_EVI', '_1_km_16_days_VI_Quality']
```

I want to convert the time variable to date format, and then only select 1 date from each year. Here is the code to convert to date format:

```
from netCDF4 import num2date
times = file_in.variables["time"]                      #import time variables
dates = num2date(times[:], times.units)                #get the time info
dates = [date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for date in dates]  #get the list of datetime
print(dates)
```

The dates are as follows:

```
['2000-06-25', '2000-07-11', '2000-07-27', '2000-08-12', '2000-08-28', '2000-09-13', '2000-09-29', '2000-10-15', '2000-10-31', '2000-11-16', '2000-12-02', '2000-12-18', '2001-01-01', '2001-01-17', '2001-02-02', '2001-02-18', '2001-03-06', '2001-03-22', '2001-04-07', '2001-04-23', '2001-05-09', '2001-05-25', '2001-06-10', '2001-06-26', '2001-07-12', '2001-07-28', '2001-08-13', '2001-08-29', '2001-09-14', '2001-09-30', '2001-10-16', '2001-11-01', '2001-11-17', '2001-12-03', '2001-12-19', '2002-01-01', '2002-01-17', '2002-02-02', '2002-02-18', '2002-03-06', '2002-03-22', '2002-04-07', '2002-04-23', '2002-05-09', '2002-05-25', '2002-06-10', '2002-06-26', '2002-07-12', '2002-07-28', '2002-08-13', '2002-08-29', '2002-09-14', '2002-09-30', '2002-10-16', '2002-11-01', '2002-11-17', '2002-12-03', '2002-12-19', '2003-01-01', '2003-01-17', '2003-02-02', '2003-02-18', '2003-03-06', '2003-03-22', '2003-04-07', '2003-04-23', '2003-05-09', '2003-05-25', '2003-06-10', '2003-06-26', '2003-07-12', '2003-07-28', '2003-08-13', '2003-08-29', '2003-09-14', '2003-09-30', '2003-10-16', '2003-11-01', '2003-11-17', '2003-12-03', '2003-12-19', '2004-01-01', '2004-01-17', '2004-02-02', '2004-02-18', '2004-03-05', '2004-03-21', '2004-04-06', '2004-04-22', '2004-05-08', '2004-05-24', '2004-06-09', '2004-06-25', '2004-07-11', '2004-07-27', '2004-08-12', '2004-08-28', '2004-09-13', '2004-09-29', '2004-10-15', '2004-10-31', '2004-11-16', '2004-12-02', '2004-12-18', '2005-01-01', '2005-01-17', '2005-02-02', '2005-02-18', '2005-03-06', '2005-03-22', '2005-04-07', '2005-04-23', '2005-05-09', '2005-05-25', '2005-06-10', '2005-06-26', '2005-07-12', '2005-07-28', '2005-08-13', '2005-08-29', '2005-09-14', '2005-09-30', '2005-10-16', '2005-11-01', '2005-11-17', '2005-12-03', '2005-12-19', '2006-01-01', '2006-01-17', '2006-02-02', '2006-02-18', '2006-03-06', '2006-03-22', '2006-04-07', '2006-04-23', '2006-05-09', '2006-05-25', '2006-06-10', '2006-06-26', '2006-07-12', '2006-07-28', '2006-08-13', '2006-08-29', '2006-09-14', '2006-09-30', '2006-10-16', '2006-11-01', '2006-11-17', '2006-12-03', '2006-12-19', '2007-01-01', '2007-01-17', '2007-02-02', '2007-02-18', '2007-03-06', '2007-03-22', '2007-04-07', '2007-04-23', '2007-05-09', '2007-05-25', '2007-06-10', '2007-06-26', '2007-07-12', '2007-07-28', '2007-08-13', '2007-08-29', '2007-09-14', '2007-09-30', '2007-10-16', '2007-11-01', '2007-11-17', '2007-12-03', '2007-12-19', '2008-01-01', '2008-01-17', '2008-02-02', '2008-02-18', '2008-03-05', '2008-03-21', '2008-04-06', '2008-04-22', '2008-05-08', '2008-05-24', '2008-06-09', '2008-06-25', '2008-07-11', '2008-07-27', '2008-08-12', '2008-08-28', '2008-09-13', '2008-09-29', '2008-10-15', '2008-10-31', '2008-11-16', '2008-12-02', '2008-12-18', '2009-01-01', '2009-01-17', '2009-02-02', '2009-02-18', '2009-03-06', '2009-03-22', '2009-04-07', '2009-04-23', '2009-05-09', '2009-05-25', '2009-06-10', '2009-06-26', '2009-07-12', '2009-07-28', '2009-08-13', '2009-08-29', '2009-09-14', '2009-09-30', '2009-10-16', '2009-11-01', '2009-11-17', '2009-12-03', '2009-12-19', '2010-01-01', '2010-01-17', '2010-02-02', '2010-02-18', '2010-03-06', '2010-03-22', '2010-04-07', '2010-04-23', '2010-05-09', '2010-05-25', '2010-06-10', '2010-06-26', '2010-07-12', '2010-07-28', '2010-08-13', '2010-08-29', '2010-09-14', '2010-09-30', '2010-10-16', '2010-11-01', '2010-11-17', '2010-12-03', '2010-12-19', '2011-01-01', '2011-01-17', '2011-02-02', '2011-02-18', '2011-03-06', '2011-03-22', '2011-04-07', '2011-04-23', '2011-05-09', '2011-05-25', '2011-06-10', '2011-06-26', '2011-07-12', '2011-07-28', '2011-08-13', '2011-08-29', '2011-09-14', '2011-09-30', '2011-10-16', '2011-11-01', '2011-11-17', '2011-12-03', '2011-12-19', '2012-01-01', '2012-01-17', '2012-02-02', '2012-02-18', '2012-03-05', '2012-03-21', '2012-04-06', '2012-04-22', '2012-05-08', '2012-05-24', '2012-06-09', '2012-06-25', '2012-07-11', '2012-07-27', '2012-08-12', '2012-08-28', '2012-09-13', '2012-09-29', '2012-10-15', '2012-10-31', '2012-11-16', '2012-12-02', '2012-12-18', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-17', '2013-02-02', '2013-02-18', '2013-03-06', '2013-03-22', '2013-04-07', '2013-04-23', '2013-05-09', '2013-05-25', '2013-06-10', '2013-06-26', '2013-07-12', '2013-07-28', '2013-08-13', '2013-08-29', '2013-09-14', '2013-09-30', '2013-10-16', '2013-11-01', '2013-11-17', '2013-12-03', '2013-12-19', '2014-01-01', '2014-01-17', '2014-02-02', '2014-02-18', '2014-03-06', '2014-03-22', '2014-04-07', '2014-04-23', '2014-05-09', '2014-05-25', '2014-06-10', '2014-06-26', '2014-07-12', '2014-07-28', '2014-08-13', '2014-08-29', '2014-09-14', '2014-09-30', '2014-10-16', '2014-11-01', '2014-11-17', '2014-12-03', '2014-12-19', '2015-01-01', '2015-01-17', '2015-02-02', '2015-02-18', '2015-03-06', '2015-03-22', '2015-04-07', '2015-04-23', '2015-05-09', '2015-05-25', '2015-06-10', '2015-06-26', '2015-07-12', '2015-07-28', '2015-08-13', '2015-08-29', '2015-09-14', '2015-09-30', '2015-10-16', '2015-11-01', '2015-11-17', '2015-12-03', '2015-12-19', '2016-01-01', '2016-01-17', '2016-02-02', '2016-02-18', '2016-03-05', '2016-03-21', '2016-04-06', '2016-04-22', '2016-05-08', '2016-05-24', '2016-06-09', '2016-06-25', '2016-07-11', '2016-07-27', '2016-08-12', '2016-08-28', '2016-09-13', '2016-09-29', '2016-10-15', '2016-10-31', '2016-11-16', '2016-12-02', '2016-12-18', '2017-01-01', '2017-01-17', '2017-02-02', '2017-02-18', '2017-03-06', '2017-03-22', '2017-04-07', '2017-04-23', '2017-05-09', '2017-05-25', '2017-06-10', '2017-06-26', '2017-07-12', '2017-07-28', '2017-08-13', '2017-08-29', '2017-09-14', '2017-09-30', '2017-10-16', '2017-11-01', '2017-11-17', '2017-12-03', '2017-12-19', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-17', '2018-02-02', '2018-02-18', '2018-03-06', '2018-03-22', '2018-04-07', '2018-04-23', '2018-05-09', '2018-05-25', '2018-06-10', '2018-06-26', '2018-07-12', '2018-07-28', '2018-08-13', '2018-08-29', '2018-09-14', '2018-09-30', '2018-10-16', '2018-11-01', '2018-11-17', '2018-12-03', '2018-12-19', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-17', '2019-02-02', '2019-02-18', '2019-03-06', '2019-03-22', '2019-04-07', '2019-04-23', '2019-05-09', '2019-05-25', '2019-06-10', '2019-06-26', '2019-07-12', '2019-07-28', '2019-08-13', '2019-08-29', '2019-09-14', '2019-09-30', '2019-10-16', '2019-11-01', '2019-11-17', '2019-12-03', '2019-12-19', '2020-01-01', '2020-01-17', '2020-02-02', '2020-02-18', '2020-03-05', '2020-03-21', '2020-04-06', '2020-04-22', '2020-05-08', '2020-05-24', '2020-06-09', '2020-06-25', '2020-07-11', '2020-07-27']
```

And these are the dates I want in the data frame:

```
dates = ['2000-07-11', '2001-07-12', '2002-07-12', '2003-07-12', '2004-07-11',
          '2005-07-12', '2006-07-12', '2007-07-12', '2008-07-11', '2009-07-12', 
          '2010-07-12', '2011-07-12', '2012-07-11', '2013-07-12', '2014-07-12',
          '2015-07-12', '2016-07-11', '2017-07-12', '2018-07-12', '2019-07-12',
          '2020-07-11']
```

I tried just defining a new `dates` data frame, but I think that caused problems for me later in the code, so I would like to just subset the first `dates` data frame if there is an easy way to do it.

Thank you for your help